# fuzzy system value error when trying to create fuzzy rules

Tags: python, jupyter, fuzzy-logic

i made a system that takes 2 inputs which is temperature and humidity and returns 2 outputs which is success_rate and health_condition. Temperature accepts cold, average, hot. Humidity accepts poor, average, good. Success rate returns low, medium, high. And health condition returns poor, average, good

This is my code:

```
pip install -U scikit-fuzzy
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl

temperature = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(38, 42.3, 1), 'temperature')
humidity = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(79.4, 84.7, 1), 'humidity')
success_rate = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 101, 1), 'success rate')
health_condition = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 101, 1), 'health condition')


temperature['cold'] = fuzz.trimf(temperature.universe, [38.0, 38.0, 40.0])
temperature['average'] = fuzz.trimf(temperature.universe, [38.0, 40.0, 42.0])
temperature['hot'] = fuzz.trimf(temperature.universe, [40.0, 42.0, 42.0])

humidity.automf(3)

success_rate['low'] = fuzz.trimf(success_rate.universe, [0, 0, 50])
success_rate['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(success_rate.universe, [0, 50, 100])
success_rate['high'] = fuzz.trimf(success_rate.universe, [50, 100, 100])

health_condition.automf(3)

rule1 = ctrl.Rule(temperature['hot'] | humidity['good'] , success_rate['low'], health_condition['poor']  )
rule2 = ctrl.Rule(temperature['hot'] | humidity['average'] , success_rate['low'], health_condition['poor'])
rule3 = ctrl.Rule(temperature['hot'] | humidity['poor'] , success_rate['low'] , health_condition['poor'] )
rule4 = ctrl.Rule(temperature['average'] | humidity['good'] , success_rate['medium'] , health_condition['average'] )
rule5 = ctrl.Rule(temperature['average'] | humidity['average'] , success_rate['medium'] , health_condition['average'] )
rule6 = ctrl.Rule(temperature['average'] | humidity['poor'] , success_rate['medium'] , health_condition['average'] )
rule7 = ctrl.Rule(temperature['cold'] | humidity['good'] , success_rate['high'] , health_condition['good'] )
rule8 = ctrl.Rule(temperature['cold'] | humidity['average'] , success_rate['high'] , health_condition['good'] )
rule9 = ctrl.Rule(temperature['cold'] | humidity['poor'] , success_rate['low'] , health_condition['poor'] )

input_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem([rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, rule5, rule6, rule7, rule8, rule9])
```

I am using jupyter notebook so when i try to run the last line it generates this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-9f38a71297a7> in <module>
----> 1 input_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem([rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, rule5, rule6, rule7, rule8, rule9])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skfuzzy\control\controlsystem.py in __init__(self, rules)
     45             if hasattr(rules, '__iter__'):
     46                 for rule in rules:
---> 47                     self.addrule(rule)
     48             else:
     49                 try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skfuzzy\control\controlsystem.py in addrule(self, rule)
    100         for r in self.rules:
    101             if r.label in labels:
--> 102                 raise ValueError("Input rule cannot have same label, '{0}', "
    103                                  "as any other rule.".format(r.label))
    104             labels.append(r.label)

ValueError: Input rule cannot have same label, 'health condition[poor]', as any other rule.
```

Does anyone have any idea where I went wrong. Because this is a very new topic to me and im not fully sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

change

```py
ctrl.Rule(temperature['hot'] | humidity['average'] , success_rate['low'], health_condition['poor'])
```

to

```py
ctrl.Rule(temperature['hot'] | humidity['average'] & success_rate['low'], health_condition['poor'])
```

you should not pass three parameters